# Adding custom title in tooltips of chart.js

Tags: javascript, chart.js

In chart.js I want to customize tooltips label with an string array. tried it in different ways but can't get my desired result. it is not replacing all the labels instead it shows all the array values in each data sets tooltips.I also tried for loop. 
here is the code pen link: 
without loop:
https://codepen.io/tumulalmamun/pen/yvNaKY
with loop:
https://codepen.io/tumulalmamun/pen/oEXzaq

```js
var tooltipsLabel = ['Dhaka','Rajshahi','NewYork','London']     

var chartList = [5,6,7,8];
            
           
       function chart(){
        var ctx = document.getElementById("myChart").getContext('2d');
            var myChart = new Chart(ctx, {
                type: 'bar',
                data: {
                    labels: ["Red", "Blue","green","Yellow"],
                    datasets: [{
                        label: '# of Votes',
                        data: chartList,
                        backgroundColor: [
                            'rgba(255, 99, 132, 0.2)',
                            'rgba(54, 162, 235, 0.2)',
                           'rgba(255, 99, 132, 0.2)',
                            'rgba(54, 162, 235, 0.2)',
                        ],
                        borderColor: [
                            'rgba(255,99,132,1)',
                            'rgba(54, 162, 235, 1)',
                             'rgba(255,99,132,1)',
                            'rgba(54, 162, 235, 1)',
                        ],
                        borderWidth: 1
                    }]
                },
                options: {
                    scales: {
                        yAxes: [{
                            ticks: {
                                beginAtZero:true
                            }
                        }]
                    },
                  tooltips: {
                    mode: 'index',
                    intersect: true,
                  
                    callbacks: {

                        title: function (tooltipItem, data) {
                          for(var i = 0; i < data.labels.length; i++)
                            {
                                 return tooltipsLabel[i];    
                            }
                       
                          
                           
                        }
                    }
                }
                }
            });
             
       }
    
       chart();
```

```html
<html>
    <head>
        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.7.1/Chart.bundle.min.js"></script>
        <link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-lg-4">
                    <canvas id="myChart" width="100" height="100"></canvas>
            </div>
            
            <div class="col-lg-4"><canvas id="pieChart" width="100" height="100"></canvas></div>
        </div>
        <script>
       
            
            </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

```js
var tooltipsLabel = ['Dhaka','Rajshahi','NewYork','London']     

var chartList = [5,6,7,8];
            
           
       function chart(){
        var ctx = document.getElementById("myChart").getContext('2d');
            var myChart = new Chart(ctx, {
                type: 'bar',
                data: {
                    labels: ["Red", "Blue","green","Yellow"],
                    datasets: [{
                        label: '# of Votes',
                        data: chartList,
                        backgroundColor: [
                            'rgba(255, 99, 132, 0.2)',
                            'rgba(54, 162, 235, 0.2)',
                           'rgba(255, 99, 132, 0.2)',
                            'rgba(54, 162, 235, 0.2)',
                        ],
                        borderColor: [
                            'rgba(255,99,132,1)',
                            'rgba(54, 162, 235, 1)',
                             'rgba(255,99,132,1)',
                            'rgba(54, 162, 235, 1)',
                        ],
                        borderWidth: 1
                    }]
                },
                options: {
                    scales: {
                        yAxes: [{
                            ticks: {
                                beginAtZero:true
                            }
                        }]
                    },
                  tooltips: {
                    mode: 'index',
                    intersect: true,
                  
                    callbacks: {

                        title: function (tooltipItem, data) {
                          
                          return tooltipsLabel;
                           
                        }
                    }
                }
                }
            });
             
       }
    
       chart();
```

```html
<html>
    <head>
        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.7.1/Chart.bundle.min.js"></script>
        <link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-lg-4">
                    <canvas id="myChart" width="100" height="100"></canvas>
            </div>
            
            <div class="col-lg-4"><canvas id="pieChart" width="100" height="100"></canvas></div>
        </div>
        <script>
       
            
            </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use tooltipItem property index to reference the item in your tooltipsLabel array:

```js
var tooltipsLabel = ['Dhaka', 'Rajshahi', 'NewYork', 'London']

var chartList = [5, 6, 7, 8];


function chart() {
  var ctx = document.getElementById("myChart").getContext('2d');
  var myChart = new Chart(ctx, {
    type: 'bar',
    data: {
      labels: ["Red", "Blue", "green", "Yellow"],
      datasets: [{
        label: '# of Votes',
        data: chartList,
        backgroundColor: [
          'rgba(255, 99, 132, 0.2)',
          'rgba(54, 162, 235, 0.2)',
          'rgba(255, 99, 132, 0.2)',
          'rgba(54, 162, 235, 0.2)',
        ],
        borderColor: [
          'rgba(255,99,132,1)',
          'rgba(54, 162, 235, 1)',
          'rgba(255,99,132,1)',
          'rgba(54, 162, 235, 1)',
        ],
        borderWidth: 1
      }]
    },
    options: {
      scales: {
        yAxes: [{
          ticks: {
            beginAtZero: true
          }
        }]
      },
      tooltips: {
        mode: 'index',
        intersect: true,
        callbacks: {
          title: function(tooltipItem, data) {
            console.log(tooltipItem);
            return tooltipsLabel[tooltipItem[0].index];
          }
        }
      }
    }
  });

}

chart();
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.7.1/Chart.bundle.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div class="row">
  <div class="col-lg-4">
    <canvas id="myChart" width="100" height="100"></canvas>
  </div>
  <div class="col-lg-4"><canvas id="pieChart" width="100" height="100"></canvas></div>
</div>
```

Comment: How can I  add a new line before concatenate another string to the return type of the tooltips? I have tried '\n' and '<br />' but it won't work. 
Example:
       return $scope.ttDocName[tooltipItem[0].index] + '\n' + $scope.docType[tooltipItem[0].index];

Comment: Check the docs here: http://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/configuration/tooltip.html#tooltip-callbacks, and this example too: http://www.chartjs.org/samples/latest/tooltips/callbacks.html